# Difference between Node js and express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am a newbie for node js. What is the use of express JS? According to my understanding it is used for web projects and has some templates like Jade and CSS.

Is there anyother extra features in express.js that make it more dominating than node.js?
Which one is better node.js or express.js when it comes to server side coding?
Diff. between Express.js and node.js.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: express is built on node.js middleware

Answer (score 112):

The comparison is not entirely correct. The difference between node.js and express.js in the level of abstraction:

1. Node.js is a *run-time environment* for building server-side *event-driven i/o application* using javascript.
2. Express.js is a *framework based on node.js* for building *web-application* using principles and approaches of node.js

So, if you write web-application, you can try to use Express.js. In all other cases, it does not suit for you.

Answer (score 52):

Express is built on top of Node, so yes Express adds more features. Node is just a Javascript environment with libraries to make it easy to write software, where Express extends Node specifically to make webservers easy to write.

Express/Connect adds the concept of middleware, a simplified way of managing different routes, automated integration with several templating engines and a bunch more.

Answer (score 19):

Express js is built on top of the Node.js framework.

Express js uses node.js itself and provides more features to build applications on top Node.js

http://expressjs.com/, if you look at this link itself it says **Express - node.js web application framework.**

Comment: Node.js is NOT a framework. It's runtime for server-side JS.