# How does Express.js relate to Node JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm seeing several responses of comparisons of Express vs Node, what each is/does but still a little unclear how one relates to the other.

Wondering if this would be a good analogy?

JavaScript : jQuery = Node.js : Express.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668880/difference-between-node-js-and-express-js

Answer (score 4):

Node.js is a platform for building server-side event-driven i/o application using javascript.

Express.js is a framework that is based on node.js for building web-application

Answer (score 2):

node.js is a Javascript runtime environment that comes with a ton of libraries.

Express is a Javascript library that runs in node.js and offers advanced features for configuring and running a web server.

So, you can have a web server in node.js without Express (the built-in http module offers a simple web server), but you cannot use Express without node.js since Express runs on top of node.js.  Express adds many more features (such as routing and middleware and tons of compatible add-ons) over the built-in web server.

Your analogy of Browser Javascript ==> jQuery as compared to Node.js ==> Express is a good comparison.  jQuery adds DOM manipulation features to regular browser Javascript while Express adds web server features to regular node.js web servers.

Comment: Thank you. Really helps. I'm new to the JavaScript world so have another question: if I don't use Node.js(/Express.js), what do I use?

Comment: @MarkS - You need an environment that supports Javascript.  node.js is one.  A browser is another.  There are others.  More importantly, you need to describe what problem you're trying to solve and then one can pick an appropriate Javascript environment for that type of problem.

Comment: How does the Express/Node model compare to Apache or Tomcat?

Comment: @MarkS - Express/Node aren't not arranged into the same pieces that Apache or Tomcat are.  Apache is a web server that has means for lots of other environments to plug into it to allow website programming.  Stand-alone Apache serves static files, but needs a programming environment added to it to give you fully dynamic pages.  Tomcat is a Java environment that contains a bunch of components.  It can serve as its own web server or it can hook into Apache's web server.  It also has a JSP module for dynamic/template pages.

Comment: @MarkS -  Node is perhaps closest to a Java environment in that it offers a language run-time and a rich library built around that language.  Just like you could build a full web server in Java alone, you could also do that in node.js alone. 
 But, express offers a web server framework on top of the http server built into node.js to make a lot of things easier.  If you want a template engine, you add another component on top of Express such as Jade, EJS, Mustache, Nunjucks, Dustjs, etc...  So, the pieces just aren't arranged in the same buckets.