# Nodejs and Expressjs difference

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference between **nodejs** and **expressjs** and
Is it possible to create webpage only using nodejs?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668880/difference-between-node-js-and-express-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Node js and express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12668880/difference-between-node-js-and-express-js)

Answer (score 0):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment for executing JavaScript code server-side. Node allows you to write and run Javascript code server-side.

[Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) is a framework for Node.js. Basically instead of writing 20 lines of code for a simple functionality with Node.js, you can write it in 2 lines using Express.js.

You can write the webapp using Node.js, but I don`t recommend it. Express is a minimalistic framework and it will make you life easier.

Answer (score -1):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment for executing JavaScript code server-side. Node allows you to write and run Javascript code server-side.

[Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) is a framework for Node.js

Express is built on top of Node, so yes Express adds more features. Node is just a Javascript environment with libraries to make it easy to write software, where Express extends Node specifically to make webservers easy to write.

Express/Connect adds the concept of middleware, a simplified way of managing different routes, automated integration with several templating engines and a bunch more.

All nodejs framework in [here](http://nodeframework.com/)

Help it help you.

Thanks.